# How to try other HTTP Error besides Error 404 using localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost, http-error

Using `localhost` server (*wamp/xampp*), is it possible to try simulate most `HTTP` errors (`400,401,402,500,503(...)`)?

I've done custom error page using `.htaccess` and PHP but I can only test for error `404`. How about other errors?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `header` in PHP.

See the documentation https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

With it you can send a HTTP header to browser.

Or if you have PHP5.4 or greater you can use this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: well @paski can you help me specify how to use the function for example if error 404 will get the same result as entering url  http://localhost/web/notexist.php

Comment: @MerekaBilang Its all in the manual links, check the comments there.